# How to reproduce and fix the cause of the crash on ios 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9, testflight

Application is crashes on iPad mini 2 Retina iOS 9.0.2.
I have crash information from the TestFlight External Tester, but I can not reproduce the error and can not find the line of code with an error.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

[image: Crash information from TestFlight]

[image]

Comment: If you want to see the specific line of code that causes the crash, I suggest you use Fabric's Crashlytics. And if you want to know the crash while you're in Xcode, then navigate to the `Break Point Navigator`. You can add an `exception breakpoint` there.

Comment: Thank you, Glenn. `exception breakpoint` does not help, since the application works on the simulator without crash.

Comment: Hmm.. One of the reasons that might cause the crash is the small memory of the device, you mentioned the crash was from `iPad Mini 2 iOS 9`. So maybe try Fabric or ask the tester how to reproduce the crash.